# ruby - rock, paper. scissors tournament

Tags: ruby

I need to implement a rock, paper, scissors tournament simulator which will play all the rounds and return the tournament.

This is my tournament array:

```
tournament = [
    [
        [ 
            ["Armando", "P"], ["Dave", "S"] 
        ],
        [ 
            ["Richard", "R"],  ["Michael", "S"] 

        ],
    ],
    [
        [ ["Allen", "S"], ["Omer", "P"] ],
        [ ["David E.", "R"], ["Richard X.", "P"] ]
    ]
]
```

where for example ["Richard", "R"],  ["Michael", "S"]  represents a game where Richard played Rock and Michael Scissors. Richard should be the winner and advance to next round.

I am trying to implement a recursive function for this but i am having trouble getting the arrays right

Here is my method:

```
 def rps_tournament_winner(tournament)

  qualifying_round_winners = []
   round_winners = []
  # last round

  if tournament.length < 1
    return
  end

  tournament.each_with_index do |round,i|   
 puts round.inspect
     qualifying_round_winners[i] = []
     round_winners = []
     round.each_with_index do |game,j|
         winner = rps_game_winner(game)
         round_winners.push winner
     end
     qualifying_round_winners[i] = round_winners

  end

  rps_tournament_winner(qualifying_round_winners)
end
```

I have invented a lot with the arrays for qualifying winners but cant figure out a solution.
Hope you can help me.
thank you.

Edit:

Here is what I should get in each iteration of the method

After frist round

```
tournament = [
    [
        [ 
            ["Dave", "S"], ["Richard", "R"] 
        ],
        [ 
            ["Allen", "S"],  ["Richard X.", "P"] 

        ]
    ]
]
```

After second round:

```
tournament = [
    [
        [ 
            ["Richard", "R"] , ["Allen", "S"]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Winner

```
["Richard", "R"]
```

**Edit:2**

here is the full code:
http://pastebin.com/gjKfiWLD

Comment: Please clarify what results you are getting with your code, and what results you want to get instead.

Comment: THe array is not passed correctly to the recursive method. it raises an exception in the rps_game_winner function becuase the game variable is not correct. I will add an edit to my post with the supposed result

Comment: Why do you need to use only arrays for that? Is there any particular reason? This is a lot confusing to do using only arrays. You could use hashes for that, that would help to better organize it (in case you must use the minimal amount of stuff as possible, for some reason, like a challenge?). Yet, the best approach would be to design something using OOP. Please give us some context regarding why you started it like that, what is your idea with this code, why only arrays, etc.

Comment: This is a homework from an online course. i cant change the tournament variable structure. also I need to use the functions defined as they give.

Comment: Unable to reproduce because `in 'rps_tournament_winner': undefined method 'rps_game_winner'`.

Comment: i have added a pastebin with full code

Comment: If it's homework, why are you asking us to help you solve it? You're supposed to figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two cases we have to consider as we recurse:

Either rps_tournament_winner's argument is a game or rps_tournament_winner's argument is a tournament. Note that a subsection of a tournament is itself a tournament (just with one fewer round). If it's a game we return the winner. If it's a subsection/tournament we recurse to find the winner of its two children.

```
def rps_tournament_winner(tournament)
    # Check if we're at a game
    if tournament[0][0].is_a? String
        return rps_game_winner(tournament)
    end
    # Otherwise keep going down the rabbit hole
    return rps_game_winner([rps_tournament_winner(tournament[0]),rps_tournament_winner(tournament[1])])
end
```

Does this help you understand?

Comment: many thanks. It works. I new it it would be much simpler that what I was doing.

Comment: @Bruno-P Some people find it helps if they draw recursion calls out on paper. Just throwing that out there for any future work you do with recursion.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. Here are the steps:

1. check if tournament[0][0] is an array 
   1.1 return the game winner
2. if not 
   2.1 recursive call the tournament function check until the end who win tour[0]
   2.2 recursive call the tournament function check until the end who win tour[0]
   2.3 recursive call the tournament function check until the end who win tour[0][1]
3. List item